# How to make Circular Logo in Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-imageview

My requirement is to make Circular Icon to `ActionBar`. I used custom view to display circular image(you can see in the screenshot.) I want to use `Home` icon(In this case, green android icon) as a circular image. How can I make `Home` icon as a Circular Image??

**Note:** In my case I'm downloading images from Server and setting it to ActionBar using `setLogo()` or `setIcon()` method.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make the image default logo of your application.
Change it in the manifest file or the drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

Action bar logo is mostly your application logo by default. So either Change your application logo to circular or whatever. If you want to change the app icon (logo). Use setLogo(int) or setLogo(Drawable) method of ActionBar. Don't forget to call setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true)

Comment: I don't want Home Icon to be static, it has to be change.

Comment: If you want to change it on the tab click, then the override method of ontabselected() takes "tab" as a parameter as well. Use that tab instance and change the App icon.

Comment: Or just get the instance of action bar anywhere and change it. 
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); // || getActionBar();
actionBar.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.new_enabled));